# TorchServe RESTful API to HTTP

Tags: rest, http, curl, pytorch, torchserve

I'm using PyTorch and would like to serve the trained model. I'm going to use TorchServe with AWS.

The RESTful API which is given by TorchServe (https://github.com/pytorch/serve/blob/master/docs/rest_api.md) is based on curl. How can I use this curl as HTTP?

Ex)

```
curl http://localhost:8080/predictions/resnet-18 -T kitten_small.jpg
```

this should be converted to

```
http://localhost:8080/predictions/resnet-18/kitten_small.jpg
```

The curl example that TorchServe gives uses -T option to transfer data.
But TorchServe RESTful API gives just 'POST /predictions/{model_name}' without the way to transfer data in HTTP.